# How to keep version number in common pom and use it in other pom files (spring maven project)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

Hi I want to keep version number in common pom file which will be getting used by other pom file. Need help how to achieve the solution.

Comment: Look for Parent Pom.  https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/

Comment: I already have parent pom. I want the versions to be in other pom that will be used by all poms. This will help for version control

Comment: You cannot import information from a pom that is not your parent POM (with the exception of `<scope>import</scope>` for `<dependencyManagement>`, but this is a totally different thing).

Comment: Can you please suggest how to create multi module spring boot project along with version control (release management)

Comment: @Ankit What exactly to you mean? Usually, all modules have the module pom as parent POM and the module POM has some outside POM as parent POM. This allows you to have the same version number throughout all modules.

Comment: Thanks @JF Meier. I got the answer. I will create a pom with spring boot dependency along with versions in it. And will add that pom in my sub modules. After performing this will revert back here.

Comment: Thanks guys.. It worked.. I created a parent pom in which I kept spring boot dependency and all versions declaration there and created child pom and used the version using ${}

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the `<version>` element in your child POMs. The version will then be derived from the parent POM.

Here's an example child POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <!--  no groupId or version here, it will be derived from parent -->



    ...
</project>
```

However, if your aim is to centralize version number management of *dependencies* then either use a Maven property for each dependency (defined in your parent POM) or use Maven's `<dependencyManagement>` feature. Either way, with these two methods you can control version number in one place: the parent POM.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I already have parent tag.. Since the child project is spring boot project. How I can use versions mentioned in parent pom

Comment: @Ankit. You mean version numbers of *dependencies* ?

Comment: Yes @perterh version number in a pom. That pom will be used by others

Comment: @Ankit. Edited my answer.